# My php code is not successfully inserting records to my database. Mysql is giving me a syntax error on the line where I specify INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

My php code is not successfully inserting records to my database. Mysql is giving me a syntax error on the line where I specify INSERT INTO

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ($dberror1);
```

```
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbsel) or die ($dberror2);
```

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `lit_order_table` (`email`, 
name_first,name_last,company,address,apt,city,state,postal_code,country,ord_options,quantity,message)

VALUES ($email,$name_first,$name_last,$company,$address,$apt,$city,$state,$postal_code,$country,$ord_options,$quantity,$message)";


$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add single quotes around string values.

Corrected SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lit_order_table (email, name_first, name_last, 
company, address, apt, city, state, postal_code, country, ord_options, quantity, message)

VALUES ('$email', '$name_first', '$name_last', '$company', '$address'
 ,'$apt', '$city', '$state', '$postal_code', '$country', '$ord_options', 
'$quantity', '$message')";
```

Answer (score 1):

connect to db and try like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lit_order_table (email, name_first, name_last, 
company, address, apt, city, state, postal_code, country, ord_options, quantity, message)VALUES ('$email', '$name_first', '$name_last', '$company', '$address','$apt', '$city', '$state', '$postal_code', '$country', '$ord_options', '$quantity', '$message')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use as below:

```
VALUES ('{$email}','{$name_first}','{$name_last}','{$company}','{$address}','{$apt}','{$city}','{$state}','{$postal_code}','{$country}','{$ord_options}','{$quantity}','{$message}')";
```

The above should work. The defined variables has to be wrapped with `'{}'` to be inserted to the database

Comment: In this application the `{}` is not needed. If the values are array elements then it's needed i.e. `{$user['email']}`. The `{}` tells PHP to process it separately.